# Will pod update command update dependency of pod when it's dependency has new version?

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I will explain by example.

I have two pods in cocoapods trunk called `PodA` and `PodB`. `PodA` has `PodB` as its dependency. Both are in same version `0.0.1`

```rb
pod 'PodA'
```

So above podfile will install `PodA` and `PodB` of version `0.0.1`.

Now I have changed the `PodB` spec and its version `0.0.2`.

On `pod update` , what will be the `PodB` version ?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PodA always point to PodB's spec version. So if you change PodB's podspec's version, you will have PodB's version 0.0.2